# Hql case statement

Tags: case, hql

```
|keyid    | test
|:----    |:----
|161289462| valid
|50578283 | valid
|UGM49O3  | valid
```

I am using below query but still getting wrong results.

```
> Select keyid,CASE WHEN keyid like '^[A-Za-z]*%' THEN 'invalid' else
> 'valid' end as test

from table
```

I am expecting below

```
|keyid    | test
|:----    |:----
|161289462| valid
|50578283 | valid
|UGM49O3  | Invalid
```

Comment: what are you getting though? and what is your goal?

Comment: I am trying to find 'Keyid' column values starting with string , if yes it is invalid else valid.

Comment: ^ goes inside [] for negation

Comment: I used CASE
WHEN  keyid RLIKE '^[A-Za-z]' THEN 'invalid'
else 'valid'
end as test. This is working !